# How can I solve simultaneous equations using np.linalg.solve?

Tags: python, numpy

I have these arrays and im using `np.linalg.solve` and this is the code -

```
A = np.array([[-3.5e11, 1.04e11],[-8.976e10, 1.79e11],[-2.69e11, -1.94e11]])
Y = np.array([8.53e17, 8.53e17, 1.527e21])

res = np.linalg.solve(A,Y)
print(res)
```

I get this error --

```
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/_2/6wzj3m7j3996pt0x621tv6w40000gn/T/ipykernel_11642/2403208688.py in <module>
      2 Y = np.array([8.53e17, 8.53e17, 1.527e21])
      3 
----> 4 res = np.linalg.solve(A,Y)
      5 print(res)
      6 

<__array_function__ internals> in solve(*args, **kwargs)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in solve(a, b)
    378     a, _ = _makearray(a)
    379     _assert_stacked_2d(a)
--> 380     _assert_stacked_square(a)
    381     b, wrap = _makearray(b)
    382     t, result_t = _commonType(a, b)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in _assert_stacked_square(*arrays)
    201         m, n = a.shape[-2:]
    202         if m != n:
--> 203             raise LinAlgError('Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square')
    204 
    205 def _assert_finite(*arrays):

LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: What are the actual equations that these matrices represent? Why do you expect that system to be solvable? The error is telling you that A must be 3x3

Comment: these values are in AU, they are the positions of spacecrafts

Comment: You need three equations with three coefficients each to solve for three unknowns using `linalg.solve`. `A` contains only two coefficients per equation

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message. It tells you that it wants your `A` matrix to be square.

You might want to instead look at a least-square solution:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html

I'd also suggest factoring out the common powers of ten, because looking at this system just screams "numerical issues!"